# How Do You Diagnose MAUI Splash Screen Issues

Tags: maui

I use a custom PNG for the splash screen in my MAUI app.  It works fine on all of the IOS emulators I run the app on.  It works fine on the Android emulator it runs on.  However, when I connect my physical Android device to my computer and deploy to it, the splash screen does not appear.

I've tried looking at the device log, but there are literally thousands of entries in there which make it problematic for troubleshooting.  What are the recommended debugging or diagnostic steps I can realistically use to track this down?

**EDIT:**

I managed to grab the device log entries during the splash screen loading and thought I would paste them here to see if anyone can make any more sense of what's going on.  Here's a color coded version of it that I formatted in Excel:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the Android API version of your physical android device?Could you please post a basic demo so that we can try to reproduce this problem on my side？

Comment: It's API 30.  I just created a brand new project and had the same results.  In short: 1) added a custom png file to the Resources\Splash folder, 2) changed the existing splash screen .svg file Build Action to MauiImage, 3) changed the Build Action for the new png file to a MauiSplashScreen, 4) added the following attributes to the splash screen attribute in the project file:  <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\wlsplash.png" Color="#ffffff" BaseSize="256,256"/>.  It works fine on the emulator running API 30, but on my physical device the image does not appear.

Comment: Additional update - I just tried on a second physical Android device running API 31 and it exhibited the same behavior - no splash screen is displayed.

Comment: Another update - I tried on a physical iPhone and neither the splash screen or app icon are correct, even though they are on the iPhone emulator.  I am just going to open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Is this the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9029)?  Thanks for your feedback and support for maui.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue I opened for this on github.